# Why can't I draw numpy matrix in tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to create Game of Life with numpy, matplotlib, and tkinter. I plan to first ask the user how much row and column will be on the game board, and the probability that a cell will spawn alive. After those information are entered, the user will press the "generate" button to start the game. However, whenever the button is pressed, the error: "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'set_canvas'" will pop out. I don't know why FigureCanvasTkAgg can't graph a numpy matrix. Is there any ways to graph a numpy matrix in the tkinter window? Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from board import Board
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)

def num():
    n1 = int(t1.get())
    n2 = int(t2.get())
    n3 = int(t3.get()) / 100.00
    initBoard = np.zeros((n1, n2))
    for row in range(0,n1):
            for column in range(0,n2):
                initBoard[row][column] = np.random.choice(np.arange(0, 2), p = [1 - n3, n3])
    #game_board = Board(n1, n2, initBoard)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(initBoard, master=root)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row = 4, column = 0)
    root.quit()

root = Tk()
root.title('Game of Life')
root.geometry('800x600')
Label(root, text="How many rows?: ").grid(row = 0)
Label(root, text="How many columns?: ").grid(row = 1)
Label(root, text="Probability of spawn (between 0 and 100): ").grid(row = 2)

t1 = Entry(root)
t2 = Entry(root)
t3 = Entry(root)

t1.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
t2.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
t3.grid(row = 2, column = 1)


Button(root, text = 'Generate', command = num).grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = W, pady = 4)

fig= plt.figure()
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row = 4, column = 0)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two problems in your code:

1. You are not using `FigureCanvasTkAgg` the right way, this class creates a canvas containing a matplotlib figure that you can integrate to your tkinter app. However, this is not with this class that you draw your plot, but with the `AxesSubplot` class (i.e. the subplot inside the `Figure`). Here is how to create the matplotlib figure and integrate it in the tkinter app:

   ```
   fig = plt.figure()  # matplotlib figure
   ax = fig.subplot_add(111)  # subplot inside figure
   canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)  # integrate the figure in a tkinter widget
   canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row = 4, column = 0)  # display figure in tkinter app
   ```

   Now, if you want to plot something in the figure, just use `ax.plot(...)` (or any other plotting function). In your case, since you want to display a 2D array so you will probably want to use `ax.imshow(initBoard)`.
2. You quit `root` in `num()`, which will destroy also the window containing your figure. What I would rather do is create a `Toplevel` to ask the user about the parameters, and close this toplevel, not the root window in `num()`.

Full code:

```
from tkinter import *  # not a good idea in my opinion, can lead to accidental 
                       # naming conflicts, "import tkinter as tk" is a better alternative
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#~from board import Board
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)

def num():
    n1 = int(t1.get())
    n2 = int(t2.get())
    n3 = int(t3.get()) / 100.00
    top.destroy()  # close dialog
    initBoard = np.zeros((n1, n2))
    for row in range(0, n1):
        for column in range(0, n2):
            initBoard[row][column] = np.random.choice(np.arange(0, 2), p=[1 - n3, n3])
    #game_board = Board(n1, n2, initBoard)
    ax.imshow(initBoard)  # draw board
    canvas.draw_idle()  # update matplotlib figure

root = Tk()
root.title('Game of Life')
root.geometry('800x600')
# create matplotlib figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)  # create axis
ax.axis('off')
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)  # A tk.DrawingArea.
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=4, column=0)

# toplevel to choose parameters
top = Toplevel(root)
Label(top, text="How many rows?: ").grid(row=0)
Label(top, text="How many columns?: ").grid(row=1)
Label(top, text="Probability of spawn (between 0 and 100): ").grid(row=2)

t1 = Entry(top)
t2 = Entry(top)
t3 = Entry(top)

t1.grid(row=0, column=1)
t2.grid(row=1, column=1)
t3.grid(row=2, column=1)

Button(top, text='Generate', command=num).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Yep, I'm able to display my matrix now. Is there any resources detailing the usages and attributes of FigureCanvasTkAgg? I searched online, and the main results are just how to embed in Tk.

Comment: @James `FigureCanvasTkAgg` is not meant to be used except for the embed part, you do all the rest with the usual matplotlib stuff which is well documented. The only thing is that you need to call `canvas.draw_idle()` each time you change the plot to refresh the figure.